# Angular2 - Fetch array through service before routing and rendering the component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, routes, frontend

I am trying to fetch data before my route renders my component. In app-component I get an array from the backend. This array is passed through ItemsServices to Statisticlist, or, that's how I want it to be. The issue is that it seems that the Statisticlist component renders before the array has been passed, so when console.log items from itemsService, it is undefined in statisticlist, but not in app component. How do I proceed to render the component AFTER the value is set in the service?

I've looked up the Resolver but I only find examples where the data is passed through in the route, most of the times it's a variable called id. I want to pass my array through a service, but load the component after it has been fetched. I'm not able to understand how I should use it in my situation.

EDIT after first suggestion: So, I've followed [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html) article as best as I could by using a Resolver. I get no errors, but nothing shows up. The itemsArray is still undefined in statisticlist-component. This is what my code looks like now.

EDIT 2: I realize now that in statisticlist-component, I'm trying `this.route.snapshot.params['items']` but items is not a parameter to the route, like in the article example.. But how I make it do what I'm trying to do, that I don't know.

EDIT 3: I've come to realize that resolver requires an observable, and this is what I'm trying now. Still now luck. Getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'items' of undefined at ItemsService.setItems (items.service.ts:11)

```
//items
export class Items {
    constructor(public items: any[]){}
}

//itemsService 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Items } from './items';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {
  public items: Items;

  setItems(items: any[]) {
    console.log(items);
    this.items.items = items;
  }

    getItems() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next(this.items)
        observer.complete();
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
}

//items-resolve
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Items } from './items';
import { ItemsService } from './items.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsResolve implements Resolve<Items>{

    constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) { }

    resolve() {
        return this.itemsService.getItems();
    }
}

        <!-- app-component.html -->
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." id="button-grp">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <a [routerLink]="['brott', region]"><button (click)='onClickCrimes(region)' type="button" class="btn btn-default">Brott</button></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <a [routerLink]="['statistik', region]"><button (click)='onClickStatistics(region)' type="button" class="btn btn-default">Statistik</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>


        //app.routing.ts
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { FeedlistComponent } from './feedlist/feedlist.component';
    import { StatisticlistComponent } from './statisticlist/statisticlist.component';
    import { ItemsResolve} from './items-resolve';

    const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
        { path: 'brott/:region', component: FeedlistComponent },
        { path: 'statistik/:region', component: StatisticlistComponent, resolve: { items: ItemsResolve} },
        { path: '', component: FeedlistComponent }
    ];

    export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);

    //statisticlist.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from '../items.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Items } from '../items';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-statisticlist',
  templateUrl: './statisticlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./statisticlist.component.css']
})
export class StatisticlistComponent implements OnInit {
  itemsArray: any[];
  items: Items; 
  constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.route.snapshot.params['items'];
    this.itemsArray = this.items.items;
    console.log(this.itemsArray);
  }
}

        <!-- statisticlist.component.html -->
<div class="margin-top">
    <div *ngIf="isDataAvailable">
        <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of itemsArray">
            <!-- ngFor, lista alla län och deras brottsstatistik -->
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
                <p>{{item?.region}}</p>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Invånare: {{item?.population}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Brott per kapita (denna veckan): {{item?.crimePerCapita}}%</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

//app.module.ts (I excluded all of the imports to make the reading easier)
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MapComponent,
        FeedlistComponent,
        FeedComponent,
        StatisticlistComponent,
        StatisticComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing,
      ],
      providers: [HttpService, ItemsService, ItemsResolve],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

My ngOnInit in statisticlist-component looks different than his in the article. He needs to fetch a contact using the id he gets through the resolver, but I just need to use the array that I get through the resolver.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You were actually on the right track. You were looking into resolvers. These resolvers cannot only return a string or another primitive type. These can also return an observable. The angular2 router will wait for that observable to resolve before rendering the component.

The basics outlines are:

Define a Resolver that fetches the data and implements the resolve interface

```
 export class ItemsResolve implements Resolve<Contact> { 

   constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) {} 

   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
      // should return an observable
     return this.itemsService.getWhatever();
   }
 }
```

Provide your resolver

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...,
    ItemsResolve
  ]
})
```

Point to this resolver in your routes definition

```
{ 
  path: 'items',
  component: ItemsComponent,
  resolve: {
    items: ItemsResolve
  }
}
```

You can find an in depth article on ThoughtRam http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Hey! Thank you for giving me suggestions. I did as stated and I read through the article. But I still have the same issue. I'll edit my question with the new code. Do you mind having another look?

Comment: Your doing `this.items.items = items`. Problem is u have not initialised `this.items. That will be undefined when you try to assign items to it.